# My slow-healing script gets faster and faster (C# / Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a FPS zombie game that is essentially a rip off of COD Nazi Zombies. I am 2 months into self-learning Unity with C# and everything is going well, however this small issue is bugging me and I could use a hand.

The Problem : The players health heals far too fast nomatter what values I change healingAmount and healingFreq to. Furthermore, the health seems to increasingly get faster. Is there an better way of writing a self heal method than to use a Coroutine?

Relevent code below...

```
public int currentHealth = 100;
public int maxHealth = 100;
public int healingAmount = 1;
public int healingFreq = 1;

public void Start()
{
    SetHealthBar(currentHealth);
}

public void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(SlowHeal());
}

    IEnumerator SlowHeal()
{
    while (currentHealth < maxHealth) 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(healingFreq); // Stops loop for a desired amount of seconds at a time.
        currentHealth += healingAmount; // Adds the desired healing amount to the players current health.
        SetHealthBar(currentHealth); // Updates healthbar to the players current health.

        if (currentHealth > maxHealth) // Limits the healing to the max in the event it may overflow
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are launching a new coroutine every time Update is called.  Update is called many, many times per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call `StartCoroutine()` method once in your `Start` method.  `StartCoroutine()` will handle regular calls to `SlowHeal()`.  Try moving your `StartCoroutine()` call to your `Start` method and see how things pan out.

Comment: Good eye, thank you. I can now understand why the healing was getting faster and faster. Because the slowHeal() was essentially being copied once per frame.

Comment: @DonalC93 See the code in my answer to insure that the coroutine continues to run after the zombie reaches maximum health.

Comment: I concur with @DonalC93 that their version allows later damage to start healing again which is what you are probably aiming to do.

Answer (score 1):

Once the zombie has healed once, there is no way to start the healing process again.  I would propose the following.

```
public void Update()
{
    if ( ( currentHealth < maxHealth ) && !healing )
    {
        healing = true;
        StartCoroutine(SlowHeal());
   }
}

IEnumerator SlowHeal()
{
    while (currentHealth < maxHealth) 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(healingFreq);

        currentHealth += healingAmount;
        if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }

        SetHealthBar(currentHealth);
    }

    healing = false;
}
```

Comment: This was a great addition. It also helped solve the issue of the healthbar reading 102% instead of 100%, because the healthbar in my code was updated before the health-correction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Topher is basically correct in his assessment on what's happening, but I would write the code differently. Likewise Chris Walsh is correct in saying you only need to call `StartCoroutine` in `Start`.

```
public void Start()
{
    SetHealthBar(currentHealth);
}

IEnumerator SlowHeal()
{
    while (true) 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(healingFreq);

        currentHealth += healingAmount;
        if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }

        SetHealthBar(currentHealth);
    }
}
```

Because the zombie will always heal once it is not at full health, there is no reason to terminate the coroutine when the zombie reaches full health: the code is already there to insure the zombie doesn't heal *above* maximum, so further healing and no healing are effectively identical.

In this way the coroutine can be started once (in `Start`) and never needs to be messed with after that. No checking for whether or not the coroutine is already running, no more bools to insure we don't start a second cortoutine, nothing special is needed if we insure that the coroutine itself never exits (coroutines are automatically stopped when the script is disabled or destroyed*).

*This does not apply to coroutines started by other, non-self objects.

Comment: This is a reasonable alternative.  I'm not sure how the zombie actually "dies" in either of our implementations, but that's beyond the scope of the question. ;-)

Comment: Just noodling on this... in either of our implementations a check for "currentHealth > 0" could be used as a death-check.

Comment: Or you check when the damage is dealt (which will always be before the coroutine gets another update).

Comment: Very true.  However, in the damage check you may want to cut off the SlowHeal process (or have SlowHeal end itself) so that you don't have the zombies "springing back to life" when they were thought to have been destroyed (although, that might be the desired effect).  Obviously, I am extrapolating a much larger solution than the question asked.

Comment: @Topher \*nodnod\*